# Kafka async publishing failure case, does it throw exception?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Below is my code for publishing message to kafka.

I need to know what happens in below cases ,

1. When message is sent async and doesnt get ack from all relicas, does it throw exception in client side ?
2. What happens when message is in buffer but never sent to kafka, does it throw exception ?
3. What happens in async publishing with retries =1 and retries =0 ?
4. After send() call it added to buffer and returned , now if it fails to sent to kafka, does it throw exception ?
5. I have a case where it failed to publish to kafka but didnt get any exception . Why ?

//Kafka

```
 Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("bootstarp.servers","");
    prop.put("acks","all");
    prop.put("retries",0); 


    KafkaProducer connection = null;
            try { 
            connection = new KafkaProducer<String, byte[]>(props);
            msg.setTopic(topic);
            msg.setDate(new Date());
            connection.send(msg);
            } catch() {

            } finally {
            connection.close();
            }
```